# When open the AllyDialog Modal, Top content should load first at beginning

Tags: javascript

When we have large content in [AllyDialog](https://a11y-dialog.netlify.app/) modal, The content is displaying.

Here the exact scenario.

I opened the dialog and comes down at the bottom content of the modal using vertical scrollbar. I closed the modal by clicking outside of the modal. I opened again the same modal now. At this point, The bottom content of the modal is displaying. But I need to show the top content of modal when opening the modal.

Here the exact code what I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>a11y-dialog (v7) demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <h1>a11y-dialog</h1>

      <p>
        <button class="link-like" data-a11y-dialog-show="my-dialog">
          <span>Open the dialog window</span>
        </button>
      </p>
    </main>

    <div
      class="dialog-container"
      id="my-dialog"
      aria-hidden="true"
      aria-labelledby="my-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="my-dialog-description"
    >
      <div class="dialog-overlay" data-a11y-dialog-hide></div>
      <div class="dialog-content" role="document">
        <button
          data-a11y-dialog-hide
          class="dialog-close"
          aria-label="Close this dialog window"
        >
          <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
            <path
              fill="currentcolor"
              d="M15.898,4.045c-0.271-0.272-0.713-0.272-0.986,0l-4.71,4.711L5.493,4.045c-0.272-0.272-0.714-0.272-0.986,0s-0.272,0.714,0,0.986l4.709,4.711l-4.71,4.711c-0.272,0.271-0.272,0.713,0,0.986c0.136,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.492,0.203c0.179,0,0.357-0.067,0.493-0.203l4.711-4.711l4.71,4.711c0.137,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.494,0.203c0.178,0,0.355-0.067,0.492-0.203c0.273-0.273,0.273-0.715,0-0.986l-4.711-4.711l4.711-4.711C16.172,4.759,16.172,4.317,15.898,4.045z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </button>

        <h1 id="my-dialog-title">Subscribe to our newsletter</h1>

        <p id="my-dialog-description">
          It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
          readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of
          using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
          letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it
          look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web
          page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a
          search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
          infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by
          accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a
          long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable
          content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem
          Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as
          opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
          readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page
          editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search
          for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
          Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident,
          sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). It is a long
          established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable
          content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem
          Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as
          opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
          readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page
          editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search
          for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
          Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident,
          sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is an "AllyDialog modal" ? is it a library ? there is no reference on this in your question!
You should read  SO guideline on  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and produce a [minimal and reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for facilitate the work of those who will waste time answering you

Comment: `But I need to show the top content of modal when opening the modal.` is not clearly a question, otherwise for modal dialog you shoud better use `<dialog>` element, with js `showModal()` method

Answer (score 0):

add this script below the code and target it with the class

```
<script>
  
  const dialog = document.getElementById('my-dialog');
  dialog.addEventListener('show', function () {
    const content = dialog.querySelector('.dialog-content');
    content.scrollTop = 0;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the answer.. I will try this in my code and update here.